# Proxyquire equivalent in Python3 unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am testing a script that looks something like this:

```
import arcpy

Class A:
    function go(x, y, z):
        arcpy.dothing(y,x,z['attr'])
```

I want to write a unit test in `python 3.6.6` that passes in dummy params and verifies that they are correctly transformed and passed to the `arcpy.dothing` method. I have used proxyquire in node for this but in python I can't figure this out. In particular the `@patch` doesn't seem to allow for capturing input arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out after a lot of experimenting. Here is what I ended up with:

```
import unittest
from a import A
from unittest.mock import patch

class Test_ATest(unittest.TestCase):   
    @patch('a.arcpy.dothing')
    def test_dothing(self, dothing):
        d = {"attr": "c"}
        obj = A()
        obj._go(1,2,d)

        dothing.assert_called_with(2,1,'c')
```